# Join two integers into one double

Tags: c

I need to transfer a double value (-47.1235648, for example) using sockets. Since I'll have a lot of platforms, I must convert to network byte order to ensure correct endian of all ends....but this convert doesn't accept double, just integer and short, so I'm 'cutting' my double into two integer to transfer, like this:

```
double lat = -47.848945;
int a;
int b;
a = (int)lat;
b = (int)(lat+1);
```

Now, I need to restore this on the other end, but using the minimum computation as possible (I saw some examples using POW, but looks like pow use a lot of resources for this, I'm not sure). Is there any way to join this as simples as possible, like bit manipulating?

Comment: This sort of "cutting" doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but that code just looks wrong.

Comment: Why not convert it into a string before you send it?

Comment: You probably want to multiply/divide and not do this

Comment: Would it be better to ask the real question (what is a way to transfer double values across the network between heterogeneous machines) than to ask how to do one particular trick that may not actually work for the job you intend.

Comment: You're overlooking a key flaw in your strategy: it's pointless.  There is no reason to suppose that differences between the representations of `double` on different machines map in a consistent way to the byte-order differences of their integer types.  Therefore, the *best* you can hope to achieve is to reconstitute the same bytes in the same order on the receiving side, and for that, you don't need to jump through such hoops as you're trying to do.

Comment: Just take the easy way that will work.  Stringify the double, transfer the ASCII numeric chars, points/commas, minus sign, whatever, to the other end and convert back to whatever real/float type  exists there.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Depending on the platform and environment, converting `double`s to/from strings might be anything but easy. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no sense.

The typical approach is to use `memcpy()`:

```
const double lat = -47.848945;
uint32_t ints[sizeof lat / sizeof (uint32_t)];
memcpy(ints, &lat, sizeof lat);
```

Now send the elements of `ints`, which are just 32-bit unsigned integers.

This of course assumes:

- That you know how to send `uint32_t`s in a safe manner, i.e. byte per byte or using endian-conversion functions.
- That all hosts share the same binary `double` format (typically IEEE-754).
- That you somehow can manage the byte order requirements when moving to/from a pair of integers from/to a single `double` value (see [@JohnBollinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43120478/2816)).

I interpreted your question to mean all of these assumptions were safe, that might be a bit over the top. I can't delete this answer as long as it's accepted.

Comment: Will the decode step work consistently on different endian-nesses?

Comment: @Baldrick Yes, assuming it's written properly of course? Since nobody has shown any decoding code, but the OP seems aware of `htonl()` and friends, I assumed OP felt confident in sending integers.

Comment: @unwind: Fair enough (please note that I'm not the downvoter here... )

Comment: @unwind: and then the next reader won't be.. what was your wording..  confident? :) good update.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Thanks. Code like this is quite literally my bread-and-butter, I have strong feelings around it. :)

Comment: Tks @unwind, this is a much better approach and I'm aware of conversions, like a said in the question. Just to other now: the code for 'restore' is simple too (lol....this is what I asked initially): [code]memcpy(&double_out,ints,sizeof double_out);[/code]. Also, I'll use uint64_t instead of 'double'. I hope this keep compatibility with data sizes.

Comment: This approach is more reasonable than the OP's, but it still makes no sense, because the whole idea is senseless.  If the two hosts share exactly the same `double` format (including byte order), then there's no point to going to this trouble.  If they don't, then breaking the `double`'s *representation* into integers, transferring their values, and then reassembing them according to some fixed scheme is in no way guaranteed to effect a faithful transfer of the *value* of the original `double`.

Comment: "using endian-conversion functions" is indeed a problem.  [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43120478/2410359)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Are you sure? I'm pretty sure `uint32_t`s can have no "holes" and have to be 32 bits, so all the bits of the `double` should be transferred safely. But sure, going through `uint32_t`s is not the most obvious way to do this, I just went with what the OP seemed to want.

Comment: @unwind, yes, I'm sure.  I go into this in more detail in my own answer.  It's not about the representation of `uint32_t`, but rather about the overall strategy.

Answer (score 2):

It's good that you're considering differences in numeric representation, but your idea for how to deal with this problem just doesn't work reliably.

Let us suppose that every machine involved uses 64-bit IEEE-754 format for its `double` representation.  (That's already a potential point of failure, but in practice you probably don't have to worry about failures there.)  You seem to postulate that the byte order for machines' `double`s will map in a consistent way onto the byte order for their integers, but that is not a safe assumption.  Moreover, even where that assumption holds true, you need exactly the right kind of mapping for your scheme to work, and that is not only not safe to assume, but very plausibly will not be what you actually see.

For the sake of argument, suppose machine A, which features big-endian integers, wants to transfer a `double` value to machine B, which features little-endian integers.  Suppose further that on B, the byte order for its `double` representation is the exact reverse of the order on A (which, again, is not safe to assume).  Thus, if on A, the bytes of that double are in the order

```
S T U V W X Y Z
```

then we want them to be in order

```
Z Y X W V U T S
```

on B.  Your approach is to split the original into a pair (STUV, WXYZ), transfer the pair in a value-preserving manner to get (VUTS, ZYXW), and then put the pair back together to get ... uh oh ...

```
V U T S Z Y X W
```

.  Don't imagine fixing that by first swapping the pair.  That doesn't serve your purpose because you must *avoid* such a swap in the event that the two communicating machines have the same byte order, and you have no way to know from just the 8 bytes whether such a swap is needed.  Thus even if we make simplifying assumptions that we know to be unsafe, your strategy is insufficient for the task.

Alternatives include:

- transfer your doubles as strings.
- transfer your doubles as integer (significand, scale) pairs.  The `frexp()` and `ldexp()` functions can help with encoding and decoding such representations.
- transfer an integer-based fixed-point representation of your doubles (the same as the previous option, but with pre-determined scale that is not transferred)

Comment: Good point that endian adjustments need to be on the whole `double` and not piece-wise portions of it.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to transfer a double value (-47.1235648, for example) using sockets.

If the platforms have potentially different codings for `double`, then sending a bit pattern of the `double` is a problem.  If code wants portability, a less than "just copy the bits" approach is needed.  An alternative is below.

If platforms *always* have the same `double` format, just copy the `n` bits.  Example:[@Rishikesh Raje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43118928/2410359)

In detail, OP's problem is only loosely defined.  On many platforms, a `double` is a [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) yet this is **not required** by C.  That `double` can represent about 2<sup>64</sup> different values *exactly*.  Neither -47.1235648 nor -47.848945 are one of those.  So it is possible OP does not have a strong precision concern.

"using the minimum computation as possible" implies minimal code, usually to have minimal time.  For speed, any solution should be rated on [order of complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)  and with [code profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)).

---

A portable method is to send via a string.  This approach addresses correctness and best possible precision first and performance second.  It removes endian issues as data is sent via a string and there is no precision/range loss in sending the data.  The receiving side, if the using the same `double` format will re-formed the `double` exactly.  With different `double` machines, it has a good string representation to do the best it can.

```
// some ample sized buffer 
#define N (sizeof(double)*CHAR_BIT)

double x = foo();
char buf[N];
#if FLT_RADIX == 10
  // Rare based 10 platforms 
  // If macro DBL_DECIMAL_DIG not available, use (DBL_DIG+3)
  sprintf(buf, "%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1, x);
#else
  // print mantissa in hexadecimal notation with power-of-2 exponent
  sprintf(buf, "%a", x);
#endif

bar_send_string(buf);
```

To reconstitute the `double`

```
char *s = foo_get_string();

double y;
// %f decode strings in decimal(f), exponential(e) or hexadecimal/exponential notation(a)
if (sscanf(s, "%f", &y) != 1) Handle_Error(s);
else use(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

A much better idea would be to send the double directly as 8 bytes in network byte order.

You can use a union

```
typedef union
{
   double a;
   uint8_t bytes[8];  
} DoubleUnionType;

DoubleUnionType DoubleUnion;
//Assign the double by
DoubleUnion.a = -47.848945;
```

Then you can make a network byte order conversion function

```
void htonfl(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in)
{
    #if LITTLE_ENDIAN   // Use macro name as per architecture
        out[0] = in[7]; 
        out[1] = in[6]; 
        out[2] = in[5]; 
        out[3] = in[4]; 
        out[4] = in[3]; 
        out[5] = in[2]; 
        out[6] = in[1];  
        out[7] = in[0];
   #else
        memcpy (out, in, 8);
   #endif  
}
```

And call this function before transmission and after reception.

Comment: The OP's datum is a `double`, not a `float`.  If it *were* a `float` then very likely it would consume only four bytes, not eight.

Comment: Oh! Corrected that.

Comment: Curious code has a concern about portability due to endianness, yet uses a fixed magic number 8 rather than `sizeof (double)`.  Using "to send the _float_ ..." with member `double a` adds ambiguity.